# systemd-networkd does not enslave interfaces on bond

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, bonding

I have installed systemd-210 on a server and i want to create a bond for 4 interfaces.
Therefore i created a 'catch-all' .network file:

**/etc/systemd/networkd/10.all-interfaces-to-bond0:**

```
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

Moreover i created the bond.netdev file:

**/etc/systemd/networkd/20.bond0.netdev:**

```
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond
```

And finally a config for the bond interface
**/etc/systemd/networkd/30.bond0.network:**

```
[Match]
Name=bond0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.59/24
Gateway=192.168.1.254
```

Now i have a 'bond0' interface that is configured correctly but has no slaves.

I have to manually type:

**# ifenslave bond0 enp2s0f0 snp2s0f1 enp5s0f0 enp5s0f1**
to enslave the interface to the bond.

Why is networkd not setting my interfaces as slaves?

in journalctl i get:

```
systemd-udevd[3666]: Could not apply link config to bond0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with systemd-211.